# Addition of 2 Dimensional Array in C#

Tags: c#

```
int[,] array2D = {{ 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6 },{ 4, 8, 6, 4, 8, 5 }};
```

> how to add row 1 and 2

Comment: It's the same way you would do it on paper..  But add them *how*? all elements in each row?  Elements at same index? Show what you've done to solve it yourself

Answer (score -1):

Possibly:

```
int[] sumRow = Enumerable.Range(0, array2D.GetLength(1))
  .Select(i => array2D[0, i] + array2D[1, i]).ToArray();
```